# Multistore Images are not coming after Upgrade 2.2.6 to 2.3

Tags: product-images, magento2.3, magento2.2.6, magento-upgrade

I have multiple stores setup with more then 100K products and 500+ categories.

So my issue is when I upgrade Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3 the product images are coming properly from main store but some products images are missing from other stores, the images path are alright but the **generated cache hash is wrong** in other stores.

I have research for the issue and found that this is the bug in Magento after upgrade, So do you guys have any alternate solution for this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: run chmod 0777 -R var pub generated 0r  chmod 0777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*

Comment: @JugalKishor thanks for your suggestion but I have already run this lots of times, do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: run php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Comment: Regenerate your images and flush the image cache from command line find doing using browser doesnt seem to work correctly

Comment: @DavaGordon I have already tried this but not working for me.

Comment: check the url it is requesting is it correct, you can check this by trying to open it in the browser if it isnt then possible check your media paths i had to put direct path within media when i did mine

Comment: my media path without cache hash is correct but if I check file in cache hash directory then images are not getting properly.

Comment: @Deva can you help me to find out issue ?

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using the image resize command to pre-generate all necessary resizes.

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

This command gets all the images sizes that have been defined in the theme XML and regenerates the images in their correct folders. after that please remove image cache and flush Magento cache

You can also check the command documentation for more information http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

Answer (score 1):

Please go into Back Office, go to

> system => cache management

flush catalog images cache

and then run

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

on command